# What does this horribly ugly (yet somehow secretly beautiful) Perl code do?

Tags: perl, formatting, deobfuscation

I found this code in a Powerpoint presentation about Perl scripting and this was on a page demonstrating how ugly Perl code can get if you really  wanted to make it that way.  The presentation says nothing about what this code does.  Honestly I am just very curious to know... It has no compilation errors so it appears to be a valid Perl script, but I can't for the life of me figure out what it does.

Here is the script:

```
$_='while(read+STDIN,$_,2048){$a=29;$b=73;$c=142;$t=255;@t=map{$_%16or$t^=$c^=(
$m=(11,10,116,100,11,122,20,100)[$_/16%8])&110;$t^=(72,@z=(64,72,$a^=12*($_%16
-2?0:$m&17)),$b^=$_%64?12:0,@z)[$_%8]}(16..271);if((@a=unx"C*",$_)[20]&48){$h
=5;$_=unxb24,join"",@b=map{xB8,unxb8,chr($_^$a[--$h+84])}@ARGV;s/...$/1$&/;$
d=unxV,xb25,$_;$e=256|(ord$b[4])<<9|ord$b[3];$d=$d>>8^($f=$t&($d>>12^$d>>4^
$d^$d/8))<<17,$e=$e>>8^($t&($g=($q=$e>>14&7^$e)^$q*8^$q<<6))<<9,$_=$t[$_]^
(($h>>=8)+=$f+(~$g&$t))for@a[128..$#a]}print+x"C*",@a}';s/x/pack+/g;eval
```

I made a few attempts at reformatting it to try and make some sense of it, but I think it would take a true Perl guru to sort this one out...

Reformatted code:

```
$_ = 'while(read+STDIN, $_, 2048) {
    $a = 29;
    $b = 73;
    $c = 142;
    $t = 255;

    @t = map {
        $_%16 or $t ^= $c ^= ($m = (11, 10, 116, 100, 11, 122, 20, 100) [$_/16%8])&110;
        $t ^= (72, @z = (64, 72, $a ^= 12*($_%16 - 2 ? 0 : $m & 17)), $b ^= $_%64 ? 12: 0, @z) [$_%8]
    } (16..271);

    if ((@a = unx"C*", $_) [20]&48) {
        $h=5;

        $_ = unxb24, join "", @b = map {
            xB8, unxb8, chr ($_^$a [--$h + 84])
        } @ARGV;

        s/...$/1$&/;
        $d = unxV, xb25, $_;
        $e = 256 | (ord $b[4]) << 9 | ord $b[3];
        $d = $d
            >> 8^($f = $t&($d >> 12^$d >> 4^$d^$d/8))
            << 17, $e = $e >> 8^($t&($g = ($q = $e >> 14&7^$e)^$q*8^$q << 6))
            << 9, $_ = $t[$_]^(($h >>= 8) += $f + (~$g&$t)) for @a[128..$#a]
    }

    print+x"C*",@a
}';

s/x/pack+/g;
eval
```

When you run the code it seems to just continuously accept user input.  I haven't been able to figure out how to make it do anything else or whether it even can do anything else.

The print statement near the end leads me to believe that there is some way to get it to a point where it will print an output though.

> Also please don't tell me to migrate this to the codegolf website...  Questions about how code functions are considered off topic for the codegolf site and are told to be redirected to StackOverflow.

Comment: It accepts input until EOF

Comment: That program generates code it latter executes. Why don't you actually look at the generated code? (Replace `eval` with `print`)

Comment: The only difference between the code shown above and the generated code is that all instances of `x` are replaced with `pack`, its still incredibly confusing after that is replaced, but thanks to Google (and thanks to you for pointing it out) there's a full explanation online. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Passing the code to Google returns [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qrpff) that explains

> `qrpff` is a Perl script created by Keith Winstein and Marc Horowitz of the MIT SIPB. It performs DeCSS in six or seven lines. The name itself is an encoding of "decss" in rot-13.

See also [`qrpff` explained](http://perl.plover.com/qrpff/article-main.html).

Comment: The claim that it is "six or seven lines" of Perl is a a little arbitrary

Comment: @Borodin, Well, the page includes an actual byte count, but the code was formatted to 80 char/lines (including newline) to display properly on an 80 char terminal. I guess that's a more "understandable" number.

Comment: Funny enough, but for the missing indentation the Perl part is just _as ugly_ as the screenshot of the C code on the wiki page.

Comment: Wow,  I didn't even bother trying Google. I assumed with all of those special characters Google would never be able to make sense of it if I just pasted the code in the search bar... I guess google did have the answer this time! Thanks @ikegami!

Comment: @tjwrona1992 For a play-by-play explanation of the code, see [qrpff Explained](http://perl.plover.com/qrpff/article-main.html) (linked in the Wikipedia article)